# Is there a way to store nested entities referencing the parent on the childs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, and I will receive request for persisting data that will include the parent(Game) and, within it, a collection with its childs(Stats). I need to persist both the parent and the childs, all at once preferably, referencing the parent on each child.

I tried

```
       repository.save(game);
```

while having this on the Game entity

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="game", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Stats> stats = new ArrayList<>();
```

Although it is persisting the child entities, the parent id is not being persisted on the DB.

I made this workaround, but I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve what I need.

```
    game = repository.save(game);
    statsService.insertGameInStats(game.getStats(), game);
    return game;
```

Comment: In general, *if it ain't busted, don't fix it*; you have something that works, so leave it. The more specific answer is what you're doing is fine.

Comment: So would you agree that using cascade can be tricky? Maybe it's always better to handle this manually?

Comment: It seems natural, logical and understandable to create the parent, fill in the children, then persist the lot (in one operation).